# 2D shape detection in 3D pointcloud

Tags: object-detection, point-clouds, pcl

I'm working on a project to detect the position and orientation of a paper plane.
To collect the data, I'm using an Intel Realsense D435, which gives me accurate, clean depth data to work with.

Now I arrived at the problem of detecting the 2D paper plane silhouette from the 3D point cloud data.

Here is an example of the data (I put the plane on a stick for testing, this will not be in the final implementation):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHaEr.gif

Basically, I have:

- A 3D point cloud with points on the plane
- A 2D shape of the plane

I would like to calculate what rotations/translations are needed to align the 2D shape to the 3D point cloud as accurate as possible.

I've searched online, but couldn't find a good way to do it. One way would be to use Iterative Closest Point (ICP) to first take a calibration pointcloud of the plane in a known orientation, and align it with the current orientation. But from what I've heard, ICP doesn't perform well if the pointclouds aren't kind of already closely aligned at the start.

Any help is appreciated! Coding language doesn't matter.

Comment: Have you tried applying ICP?

Comment: Yeah, I tried using ICP, but it didn't get me the results I was hoping for. The plane may be in a completely different orientation than the original calibration orientation, in which case ICP is really struggling to find a good fit...

Answer (score 0):

Does your 3d point cloud have outliers? How many in what way?

How did you use ICP exactly?
One way would be using ICP, with a hand-crafted initial guess using

```
pcl::transformPointCloud (*cloud_in, *cloud_icp, transformation_matrix);
```

(to mitigate the problem that ICP needs to be close to work.)

What you actually want is the plane-model that describes the position and orientation of your point-cloud right?

A good estimator of your underlying function can be found with: [pcl::ransac](https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/random_sample_consensus.html)
[pcl::ransace model consensus](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_sample_consensus_model_plane.html)

You can then get the computedModel coefficents.

Now finding the correct transformation is just: [How to calculate transformation matrix from one plane to another?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2470709/how-to-calculate-transformation-matrix-from-one-plane-to-another)